# Error while installing libxml-ruby on windows : need libxml2

Tags: ruby, windows, libxml2, devkit, libxml-ruby

I installed Ruby x64 on windows then the development kit following these instructions mentionned in a solution I found in the forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417544/having-trouble-installing-libxml-ruby-on-windows) :

1. Download and install the latest Ruby for your architecture from rubyinstaller.org
2. Download the matching DevKit from the same page
3. Extract the DevKit and follow the setup instructions, particularly step 4
4. Copy zlib1.dll from /bin to /lib
5. Download the MinGW iconv package and extract everything in mingw64/lib to /lib
6. Download libxml for windows (see below). Extract the contents of its lib into your /lib and the contents of its include directory into /include

But in the last step when I try to install libxml-ruby gem by executing this instruction 'gem install libxml-ruby', I get this error:
extconf failure: need libxml2

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have `libxml2` library installed. Download it from [here and install](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libxml2.htm). Let us know if it helps.

Comment: Actually, I have installed libxml2 (in step 6) and I got the error. And now I have installed the version you sent and I get the same error. 
I am using windows server 2008 R2