# Issue installing libxml-ruby for Windows Ruby version 2.3.3. Missing xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, libxml2

I have looked through most answers involving install issues with the libxml-ruby gem, and I got stuck on this issue with no solution. I am currently running Ruby 2.3.3.

This is the current command I am using:

```
gem install libxml-ruby -- --with-xml2-lib=C:\Ruby-2.3.3\lib --with-xml2-include=C:\Ruby-2.3.3\include
```

The resulting issue is:

```
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,
/usr/local/include/libxml2,
/usr/include/libxml2... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

xmlParseDoc() is in Parser.h, but is missing somewhere I cannot find. Has anyone else run into this same issue, and found a solution?

---

I got it working when I downgraded to libxml-ruby 2.7 with the same command. I would still like to figure out why the new version is unable to be installed. I eventually need 2.8.0 or above, which were causing this issue.

Comment: When I have to develop on a Windows machine I use a VM containing Ubuntu and develop in that environment. It's _much_ easier to write in non-Microsoft languages using a *nix environment.

Comment: Maybe you should follow the advice given by `extconf.rb` and check the `mkmf.log` file for more details?

Comment: Has to be Windows, I have looked at the mkmf.log file, and it is the same information. Can't figure out a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. What worked for me is I first followed the instructions in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417544/having-trouble-installing-libxml-ruby-on-windows/33685307). After I had to go find some of the missing pieces from libiconv; I got those from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libiconv/). I extracted its lib and include contents, into like the above solution (lib into Ruby lib, include into Ruby include). After I had to change `#include <iconv.h>` in encoding.h. This needed to be changed to `#include <path-to-/iconv.h>`, which was extracted into Ruby's include directory earlier. I was able to run `gem install libxml-ruby -- with-xml2-include=C:/Ruby23/include/libxml2 --with-iconv-include=C:/Ruby23/include`.